# Idam Identity Server Integration with Spring Boot and Spring Security – SAML2 Protocol for my application and deploy my war file in virtual

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, saml

**this is SAML Security Configuration code :**

```
`package in.gov.mca.helpdesk.saml;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.extensions.saml2.config.SAMLConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.saml.userdetails.SAMLUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SAMLSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${saml2.metadata-path}")
    private String metadataPath;

    @Value("${saml2.sp.protocol}")
    private String spProtocol;
    @Value("${saml2.sp.host}")
    private String spHost;
    @Value("${saml2.sp.path}")
    private String spBashPath;
    @Value("${saml2.sp.key-store.file}")
    private String keyStoreFile;
    @Value("${saml2.sp.key-store.password}")
    private String keyStorePassword;
    @Value("${saml2.sp.key-store.alias}")
    private String keyStoreAlias;
    
    @Value("${saml2.entity-id}")
    private String entityID;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLUserDetailsService samlUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/helpdesk/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().apply(saml())/* .and().saml2Login() */;
         

    }

    @Bean
    public  SAMLConfigurer saml() throws Exception {

        return SAMLConfigurer.saml().userDetailsService(samlUserService)
                .serviceProvider().protocol(spProtocol)
            .hostname(spHost).basePath(spBashPath).keyStore().storeFilePath(keyStoreFile)
                .keyPassword(keyStorePassword)
                .keyname(keyStoreAlias) .and().and()
                .identityProvider()
                .metadataFilePath(metadataPath).and();
    }`
```

**application.properties file :**

`saml2.metadata-path=classpath:static/samlauthentication/idammetadata.xml saml2.entity-id=http://172.18.102.233:14100/oam/fed saml2.sp.protocol=http saml2.sp.host=172.18.21.156:8080 saml2.sp.path=/ saml2.sp.key-store.file=classpath:static/samlauthentication/helpdeskkeystore.p12 saml2.sp.key-store.alias=helpdeskmcasamlauth saml2.sp.key-store.password=changeit.`

**this is my controller page**
`@Controller
public class LandingPageController {

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    // Add any common model attributes for the landing page
    model.addAttribute("searchType", "searchfouser");
    return "index"; // Return the main page template (index.html)
}
```

}`

above are the code I am looking for a SAML authentication for my helpdesk application on virtual machine(server).
what I am doing maven install after that war file will generate I am taking that war file and kept it inside the virtual machine's atomcat webapps folder and I am triggering the url

it's given me whitelabel error 505 internal server error

I tried changing few code and tried change url and different war files but still get same issue it's not able to trigger the Idam login page , struck in the whilelabel error .

what I am expecting here is check my code for saml authentication for Idam , I need to change any code . and any things , give me solution  as soon as possible .

```
type here
```